# Jquery selector to "this" return

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code:

```
function checkBoxOpenStatus(clickedBox) {
    if($("#productsBox").hasClass("boxOpen")) {
         closeBox(obj.productsBox.bx, clickedBox);
         delay = 200; 
    } else if($("#fabricationBox").hasClass("boxOpen")) {
         closeBox(obj.fabricationBox.bx, clickedBox);
         delay = 200;
    } else if($("#aboutPBBox").hasClass("boxOpen")) {
         closeBox(obj.aboutPBBox.bx, clickedBox); 
         delay = 200;
    } else { delay = 0; }
```

My goal is to evaluate three boxes, if one of them has class "boxOpen", then I need to close that box, and add a delay to my "openSelectedBox" function (not present above). My question is, can I change the above code to the following: (without loosing the ability to send a specific selector?)

```
    if($("#productsBox" || "#fabricationBox" || "#aboutPBBox").hasClass('boxOpen') {
        closeBox(obj.(**WHAT SELECTOR CAN GO HERE??**).bx, clickedBox);
        delay = 200;
```

I know the "or" evaluation works, but I don't know how to use that "or" defined instance to fire the "closeBox" function with the appropriate selection. I would rather learn that take, so please give me an explanation which selector could work there while performing an evaluation like this.

Comment: What's `obj`? Why are the functions you call not present (`closeBox`, `openSelectedBox`)? Make a self-contained sample.

Comment: Actually your or evaluation don't works as it only returns the first string. Check this in your console `console.log("first" || "second" || "three");`. It only checks the class of the first box. The other 2 are ignored.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You noticed duplicated code blocks and wanted to optimize them. (Insert I like you meme here).

You can do it this way:

```
// This will get the 3 elements in a jQuery object and filter the 3 elements to only keep the ones that have the class "boxOpen"
var theOnesWithTheClass = $("#productsBox, #fabricationBox, #aboutPBBox").filter(".boxOpen");

// This will call the closeBox with the id of each element inside the jQuery object. I do it this way just in case there are more than 1 element.
// The jQuery each method will call the function setting the this context to each element inside the jQuery object.
theOnesWithTheClass.each(function() {
    closeBox(obj[this.id].bx, clickedBox);
});

// This will set the delay to 200 only if there are elements inside the jQuery object. The ? conditional returns the block before the : if true and the block after it if false.
delay = theOnesWithTheClass.length > 0 ? 200 : 0;
```

Comment: I understand there are things out of place. I am learning javascript, html, css and jquery alone and with limited Internet. Thank you for your exmplanations.

Comment: @sirjackk1888 Np :P

Answer (score 0):

Use a selector that matches all the boxes with the class. If this returns at least 1 element, there's an open box, and you can get this element's ID.

Then you can use another selector to get the ID of the element with the class.

```
var openBoxes = $("#productBox.boxOpen, #fabricationBox.boxOpen, #aboutPBBox.boxOpen");
if (openBoxes.length > 0) {
    var openId = openBoxes.attr("id");
    closeBox(obj[openId].bx, clickedBox);
    delay = 200;
} else {
    delay = 0;
}
```

It would be a little simpler if you gave all these boxes a common class, instead of having to list all the IDs in the selector.

Comment: You can get all inputs with class "boxopen" using jQuery like I mentioned below. Like this $(".boxopen"). That way you don't have to do any if and else. I will update my code.